# Writing to a file in C# VS2012

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2012

I am using the following code to write to a file inside my project root folder..

```
public class Service2 : IService2
{

    public Boolean SaveInfo(String firstName, String lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth,
    String email, String streetAddress, String suburb, String state, int postcode,
    Job job)
    {
        string text = firstName + " " + lastName + " " + dateOfBirth + " " + email + " " + streetAddress + " " + suburb + " " + state + " " + postcode + " " + job;
        String[] people = Regex.Split(text, " ");
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Person.txt", true))
        {
            foreach (string c in people)
            {
            file.Write(c);
            file.Close();
            return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Basically it returns a boolean dependent on whether the file gets written or not... I am having trouble actually finding what gets written to the file. It does return true when executed - I run the WCF service in the WCF tester and invoke it with values to write to the file...However when I open the Person.txt file from the Solution explorer on the right hand side, nothing gets written into it...

So my question is, Is this the best way to write lines of text into a text file, and if so, where have I gone wrong?

Regards

Comment: You are closing the file and returning after writing the first person - is that what you intended?

Comment: Ah yeah i see^^ but damn.. still empty file, maybe theres a wrong setting or something

Comment: I must be missing something: why do it in a `foreach` why not just `Write(people[0])`

Comment: no i see what you mean originally John3136 and realise i was closing the file after the firstName had been written

Comment: Is this a permissions problem ? Does the account have sufficient privs to write to the file ?

Comment: Yeah running it on VS2012 admin so it should be fine, maybe i might try reading from the file to see if its accessing it properly

Comment: You could add some `try.. catch` blocks to trap any errors. Set `AutoFlush` on your `StreamWriter` ? I'm not sure about the manual file `Close()` when you're in a `USING` statement ?

Comment: @bhs must be something else because I just tried to write a simple "test" to the file and it's not letting me to that either... no idea what is going wrong

Comment: try changing the location of your file to somewhere you definitely know can be written to

Comment: @Bhs good idea, it wrote to the file when it was in C drive...Interesting

Comment: In your original code, if `firstname` is an empty string, you are going to get an empty file. Maybe put a `Console.Writeline(firstname)` and see what comes out?

Answer (score 1):

Try use this code

```
string text = firstName + " " + lastName + " " + dateOfBirth + " " + email + " " + streetAddress + " " + suburb + " " + state + " " + postcode + " " + job;
        String[] people = text.Split(" ");

if (!File.Exists("Person.txt"))
        {
            // Create a file to write to. 

            File.WriteAllLines(path, people , Encoding.UTF8);
        }
else
 File.AppendAllText("Person.Text", people , Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: Same with this one... Still no luck I open the Person.txt document afterwards and there is nothing in it...

Comment: just verify which path it writes the file. Give a try with absolute path instead of relative path.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public Boolean SaveInfo(String firstName, String lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth,
String email, String streetAddress, String suburb, String state, int postcode)
    {
        string text = firstName + " " + lastName + " " + dateOfBirth + " " + email + " " + streetAddress + " " + suburb + " " + state + " " + postcode + " ";
        String[] people = Regex.Split(text, " ");
        try
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Person.txt", true))
            {
                foreach (string c in people)
                {
                    file.Write(c);
                }
                file.Close();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            return  false;
        }

    }
```

You were closing your file after the first string in the Array, but have to close it after you've looped through every string in the Array.
For me it's working, but we may need to see your function call

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public Boolean SaveInfo(String firstName, String lastName, DateTime dateOfBirth,
    String email, String streetAddress, String suburb, String state, int postcode,
    Job job)
    {
     try{
            string text = firstName + "\r\n" + lastName + "\r\n" + dateOfBirth + "\r\n" + email + "\r\n" + streetAddress + "\r\n" + suburb + "\r\n" + state + "\r\n" + postcode + "\r\n" + job;

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("Person.txt"))
           {
               file.WriteLine(text );
               file.Close();
               return true;   
           }
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
           return false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Tried this...Still when I open the file after i close the WCF tester, the file is empty =/

Answer (score 0):

An old fashioned way

```
    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(yourFilePath)) 
    {
        byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(text);
        fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
    }
```